# How to detect and log deadlocks in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, deadlock

I want to detect and log all the deadlocks that occurred in my PostgreSQL server, preferrably including the details of the queries. Is this possible in PostgreSQL.

I want a solution like Extended Events provide in MS SQL.

Comment: As well as the logging mentioned by @LaurenzAlbe below, you might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489244/how-to-detect-query-which-holds-the-lock-in-postgres) interesting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detection happens automatically, and so does logging, unless you set `log_min_messages` to `fatal` or `panic`.

The deadlock event and the involved statements are written to the PostgreSQL log (and you cannot log them to a different file). That information is typically insufficient to determine the root cause (because that typically depends on prior statements in the same transaction, about which PostgreSQL retains no memory).

Ideally, by seeing the statements logged with the deadlock, you can determine what the application was doing and go from there, but some sleuthing cannot be avoided.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have checked that deadlock is detected in the log but there is so little information provided. I am searching for the ways to build smth that will give me both queries, IP, client name, the time and all the required fields. Is there a way to catch the deadlock and in that exact moment get the information required? I have mentioned XEvents, because my desired solution is similar to that. I need detailed information. Is this possible?

Comment: Desireably, I would like to log them in  a separate file or table not to dig all the logs each time

Comment: I tried to address your question in the answer, but you can't get what you want.